# Linking Object Files in a C program - Duplicate String Literals

Tags: c, gcc, clang, ld, string-literals

If 2 source file have the same string literal stored. I compiled both into object files and link them with my gcc or clang linker.  Will the linker remove the duplicate string literal and make both part (object files) refer to the same string literal ?

Comment: Why is this of interest, just curiosity?  If space is a real concern, put your long string literals in one .c file.  Note the same `printf()` formats are often coded in various .c files.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about your system, but when I try it I get an executable file in which the string appears only once.  Inspect your executable and see what happens for you.

Comment: You can check it by your own

Answer (score 0):

Probably but the behaviour is not guaranteed.

See the GCC option `-fmerge_constants` which puts constants into `ro_data` sections with the section header flag `SHF_MERGE`:

> Each element in the section is compared against other elements in sections with the same name, type and flags. Elements that would have identical values at program run-time may be merged.

Although only advisory, most commonly-used linkers try to respect the flag.